# pandas merge two columns with customized text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having following dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
                    'Buy': [True, True, False, False, False],
                    'Sell': [False, False, True, False, True]
                   },
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
df1

    Name    Buy Sell
0   A0  True    False
1   A1  True    False
2   A2  False   True
3   A3  False   False
4   A4  False   True
```

I want to merge Buy and Sell columns on a condition that if "Buy" is having True value then "Buyer" if "Sell" has True value then "Seller" and if both "Buy" and "Sell" has False value then it should have "NA"

```
sample required output

    Name    Type 
0   A0      Buyer
1   A1      Buyer
2   A2      Seller
3   A3      NA
4   A4      Seller
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `np.select`

```
a = np.select([df1.Buy, df1.Sell], ['Buyer', 'Seller'], 'NA')
pd.DataFrame({'Name': df1.Name, 'Type': a})

  Name    Type
0   A0   Buyer
1   A1   Buyer
2   A2  Seller
3   A3      NA
4   A4  Seller
```

---

```
df1.assign(Type=np.select([df1.Buy, df1.Sell], ['Buyer', 'Seller'], 'NA'))

  Name    Buy   Sell    Type
0   A0   True  False   Buyer
1   A1   True  False   Buyer
2   A2  False   True  Seller
3   A3  False  False      NA
4   A4  False   True  Seller
```

Comment: Any reason you use `pd.DataFrame` and `assign` over simply: `df['Type'] = np.select([df1.Buy, df1.Sell], ['Buyer', 'Seller'], 'NA')`?

Comment: @Erfan yes.  I tend to offer answers that don't alter the original dataframe.  I don't always do this... but almost always I do.

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
s = df[['Buy','Sell']]
df['Type'] = (s@s.columns).add('er').replace('er', np.nan)

# or 
# df['Type'] = np.where(s.any(1), s.idxmax(1).add('er'), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
  Name    Buy   Sell    Type
0   A0   True  False   Buyer
1   A1   True  False   Buyer
2   A2  False   True  Seller
3   A3  False  False     NaN
4   A4  False   True  Seller
```

Comment: can you tell more about `s@s.columns` ?

Comment: @YOLO that's just `dot` product, or `matmul`.

Comment: Dot multiplication [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas-dataframe-dot)